# How to redirect a page without rewrite URL?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have domain site.com and there is subdomain sub.site.com
Once you open sub.site.com you have to see site.com/sub/ without URL formatting.
How to do this?

Comment: You think the web server that you are using might be relevant?

Comment: You should define a language ;) in which you want to redirect. You cann redirect with every language.

Comment: Anton, please post what have you tried in your next questions; The community is here to help, but you must also show what you tryed; You will see soon that people will ask: What have you tryed? even links would do this job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual host, or vhost, to do so. There you can easily define a Server Alias, that transparently redirects to your directory.

For example, if your apache configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 13.37.13.37>
DocumentRoot /www/where/ever/your/webroot/is
ServerName www.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

And now you add a second Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost 13.37.13.37>
DocumentRoot /www/where/the/other/site/is
ServerName example.net
ServerAlias othersite.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Is there way without using root permissions? I do not have one.

Comment: No. Then you have to use a .htaccess and mod_rewrite. But your url will lose its 'prettyness'...